# How do I deal with pixels in pygame?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, pixel

While working with sprites in pygame, I eventually realized (due to minimal difference) that one cannot move a sprite by a fraction of a pixel. Albeit being a logical process, I came to the conclusion that equal velocity is unattainable at different angles.

For example:

```
xmove = 5
ymove = -5
```

I define the movement increments of the two coordinates of the sprite `ball` that leaves a platform on the bottom of the screen traveling at a 45° angle. I wish for this direction to change relative to the obstacles that it will encounter.

The following determines the collision of the sprite with the "walls" of the screen:

```
if ball.rect.left<=0:
    xmove = 5
elif ball.rect.right>=700:
    xmove = -5  
elif ball.rect.top<=0:
    ymove = 5
elif ball.rect.bottom>=400:
    ymove = -5
```

Here is some code to decide what happens after a collision with a `player` sprite (the platform) is detected:

```
if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(ball, player_sprite, False):# and ball.rect.bottom>=player.rect.top:
    ymove=-5
    if ball.rect.bottomright [0] in range (player.rect.topleft [0], player.rect.topleft [0] + 15):
        xmove = -5
    elif ball.rect.bottomleft [0] in range (player.rect.topright [0] - 14, player.rect.topright [0] + 1):
        xmove = +5
    elif ball.rect.bottomright [0] in range (player.rect.topleft [0] + 15, player.rect.topleft [0] + 26):
        xmove = -4
        ymove = -5.83
    elif ball.rect.bottomleft [0] in range (player.rect.topright [0] - 26, player.rect.topright [0] - 15):
        xmove = +4
        ymove = -5.83
```

> The idea here is to have the ball bounce at different angles based on where it hits the platform, all while keeping the same velocity (distance traveled per tick)

So the problem here is that to compensate the decrease of one pixel on the x coordinate I use the Pythagorean theorem to output the y coordinate (-5.83). Being that pygame doesn't register fractions of a pixel, this will actually decrease the velocity of the ball significantly.

So my question is, how do I get around this (as I don't want to be limited to 45° angles...)?

Comment: With rounding? Will one pixel each way make that much difference?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I deal with pygame pixels?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28254496/how-do-i-deal-with-pygame-pixels)

Comment: @jonrsharpe yeah rounding makes a huge difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Pygame's `Rect` is meant to deal with pixels and pixels are fundamentally indivisible, you'll have to store the precise location of `ball` using floats. `pygame.Rect` will *accept* floats, but only *stores* integer floor values.

Consider giving `ball` new `float` attributes `ball.x` and `ball.y` (if those are not yet assigned) which keep the precise (decimal) location, and then applying your `xmove` and `ymove` values to those on update. After every move (presumably as part of that same update), revise `ball.rect` so that it's `topleft` matches the x and y values, using your favourite rounding method to give `int` values. You could also make `ball.rect` a `property` which generates a new `Rect` whenever it's called. Consider:

```
class MyBall:
    @property
    def rect(self):
        return pygame.Rect(round(self.x), round(self.y), *self.size)

    def __init__(self, startingLoc, size, *args, **kwargs):
        self.x = float(startingLoc[0])
        self.y = float(startingLoc[1])
        self.size = size  # Size does not need to be floats, but can be.
          # ...
```

Be aware that if you make `ball.rect` a `property`, in-place `pygame.Rect` operations *will not work,* since `ball.rect` is generated on-the-spot and its attributes are not saved by `ball`. Rect moves can only be accomplished by altering `ball.x` and `y`, but as long as you don't act on `ball.rect` directly (or call upon `pygame` to do so), it won't matter and you'll have your precise x and y locations for `ball`.

If you want to be super-precise, you can even use the floats in your `player`-`ball` collision detection by replacing `if ball.rect.bottomright [0] in range (player.rect.topleft [0], player.rect.topleft [0] + 15):` with something like `if player.left <= ball.x <= player.left + 15:` (and so forth). Be aware that `range(..)` will not work reliably with `float` values since the range consists of whole numbers only.

When you `blit` `ball`, you will have to send `int` values for its xy location. `ball.rect.topleft` is still probably the way to go (since it pulls those values indirectly from `ball.x` and `y` on-the-spot).

`xmove` and `ymove` do not *need* to be floats; as long as at least one element in an operation is a `float`, the result will also be a `float`. After you calculate the x and y displacement for ball according to its speed and direction, you can send those float values to `ball.x` and `y`, and it will retain the precision between frames.

Comment: Ok thanks for this great idea. May I ask what the `@property` does? I'm not familiar with this command.

Comment: From what I understand, it makes so the `return` command outputs within the class, is this correct?

Comment: @AndresStadelmann `@property` is a wrapper that simplifies property assignment. I'm not totally confident in my ability to describe how a `property` works, so here are a couple of links! [http://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php] (Here's a rundown on what they are,) and [http://blaag.haard.se/What-s-the-point-of-properties-in-Python/](here's a bit about wrappers.)

Comment: If I had to explain it, I'd say that a `property` is somewhere between an **attribute**, which cannot, of itself, perform operations, and a `function` (or `lambda`), which need to be called and don't hold data so well. In this case, `ball.rect` is actually a simple function that returns a new (and unbound) `Rect` based on other attributes in `ball`, but only after performing a few operations on it. A regular attribute cannot ordinarily perform operations, but calling a function would be unwieldy. *(I do not know if I am doing the concept justice; search around for better explations!)*

Comment: So to answer your second question as it was asked, when a `property` is called, it runs the function inside the wrapper (`@property`, in this case, as a *getter* -- look up *setter*s for more info!) and passes back the `return` result as though it were an attribute value.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property I found similar documentation here, thanks

Comment: @AndresStadelmann Be aware that the doc you've linked is for Python 2, and your question is tagged for Python 3. I'm not sure if `property` varies at all between the two versions, but it might!

Comment: Oh also, for anyone using Python2, make sure you define your classes as `objects` (or a subclass of one); something like `MyBall(object)`, since oldstyle classes don't work with properties in the way we need them to here.

Comment: Thanks for the dedication, I appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

You should keep track of the *"real"* position of your object and only round the moment you draw you object on the screen. This prevents rounding errors to add up.

---

Also, consider using vectors to keep track of the direction of your object, since it makes it easy to change the direction with angles and keeping a constant speed.

Here's a little example class you could use:

```
import math

# some simple vector helper functions, stolen from http://stackoverflow.com/a/4114962/142637
def magnitude(v):
    return math.sqrt(sum(v[i]*v[i] for i in range(len(v))))

def add(u, v):
    return [ u[i]+v[i] for i in range(len(u)) ]

def sub(u, v):
    return [ u[i]-v[i] for i in range(len(u)) ]    

def dot(u, v):
    return sum(u[i]*v[i] for i in range(len(u)))

def normalize(v):
    vmag = magnitude(v)
    return [ v[i]/vmag  for i in range(len(v)) ]

class Ball(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.x, self.y = (0, 0)
        self.speed = 2.5
        self.color = (200, 200, 200)
        self._direction = (1, 0)

    # the "real" position of the object
    @property
    def pos(self):
        return self.x, self.y

    # for drawing, we need the position as tuple of ints
    # so lets create a helper property
    @property
    def int_pos(self):
        return map(int, self.pos)

    def set_dir(self, direction):
        self._direction = normalize(direction)

    def set_dir_d(self, degrees):
        self.set_dir_r(math.radians(degrees))

    def set_dir_r(self, radians):
        self._direction = (math.cos(radians), math.sin(radians))

    def update(self):
        # apply the balls's speed to the vector
        move_vector = [c * self.speed for c in self._direction]
        # update position
        self.x, self.y = add(self.pos, move_vector)

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, self.int_pos, 4)
```

This way, you can alter the direction of the ball by just calling `set_dir` (provide a vector), `set_dir_d` (provide the desired direction in degreees) or `set_dir_r` (provide the desired direction in radians).

Calling `update` will move the ball at a constant speed (the `speed` field) according to its current direction.

Comment: Alright nice, thanks! So would the vector be a list of it's components? And is the attribute `_direction` special because of the `_`?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. It's just a convention that you don't access such members directly from outside the class. It means don't set _direction directly, use the set_dir function