# How to have an object run directly away from mouse at a constant speed

Tags: python, vector, pygame, trigonometry

I have a ship that shoots lasers. It draws a line from itself to (mouseX, mouseY). How can I have the ship accelerate in the exact opposite direction as if being pushed backwards?

I have been working through some trig and ratios but am not making much progress. Acceleration is constant so how far the mouse is doesn't matter, just the direction.

I've been primarily working on trying to create a vector that only works with integers in the range (-4,4), as I cannot have the ship move across the screen at a Float speed, and the (-4,4) range would at least give me... 16 different directions for the ship to move, though I'd like that not to be a limitation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no trigonometry involved, just vectors.  If you take the subtract the position of the mouse from the position of the ship

```
(shipX-mouseX, shipY-mouseY)
```

that gives you the direction in which to move the ship.  Multiply it by some factor, round it to integers, and add it to the ship's current position.  You may want to do this a few times, to give some continuous motion.  Also, you may want the factor to vary: increase the first few ticks, and then decrease to zero.

Comment: Well... Yup.. Thats it.. I had trouble connecting the dots in my head, its so simple its confusing. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

The vector of acceleration will be in the direction from the mouse cursor to the ship, away from the mouse position - so if the line from mouse to ship is at angle theta to horizontal (where anticlockwise theta is +ve, clockwise is -ve), so will the force F acting on the ship to accelerate it. If ship has mass M then using f=ma, acceleration A will be F/M. Acceleration in x axis will be A * cos(theta), in y A * sin(theta) - then use v=u+at after every time interval for your simulation. You will have to use floating point maths for this calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full example using simple vector math. Note the comments.

```
import pygame
import math

# some simple vector helper functions, stolen from http://stackoverflow.com/a/4114962/142637
def magnitude(v):
    return math.sqrt(sum(v[i]*v[i] for i in range(len(v))))

def add(u, v):
    return [ u[i]+v[i] for i in range(len(u)) ]

def sub(u, v):
    return [ u[i]-v[i] for i in range(len(u)) ]    

def dot(u, v):
    return sum(u[i]*v[i] for i in range(len(u)))

def normalize(v):
    vmag = magnitude(v)
    return [ v[i]/vmag  for i in range(len(v)) ]

class Ship(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x, self.y = (0, 0)
        self.set_target((0, 0))
        self.org_speed = 0.9
        self.speed = self.org_speed
        self.laser = (None, 0)

    @property
    def pos(self):
        return self.x, self.y

    # for drawing, we need the position as tuple of ints
    # so lets create a helper property
    @property
    def int_pos(self):
        return map(int, self.pos)

    @property
    def target(self):
        return self.t_x, self.t_y

    @property
    def int_target(self):
        return map(int, self.target)   

    def set_target(self, pos):
        self.t_x, self.t_y = pos

    def update(self):
        if self.speed < self.org_speed:
            self.speed += min(self.org_speed, 0.3)

        # if we won't move, don't calculate new vectors
        if self.int_pos == self.int_target:
            return 

        target_vector = sub(self.target, self.pos) 

        # a threshold to stop moving if the distance is to small.
        # it prevents a 'flickering' between two points
        if magnitude(target_vector) < 2: 
            return

        # apply the ship's speed to the vector
        move_vector = [c * self.speed for c in normalize(target_vector)]

        # update position
        self.x, self.y = add(self.pos, move_vector)

    def draw(self, s):
        pygame.draw.circle(s, (255, 0 ,0), self.int_pos, 5)
        end, state = self.laser
        if state > 0:
            pygame.draw.line(s, (255, 255, 0 if state % 2 else 255), self.pos, end, 2)
            self.laser = end, state - 1

    def fire(self, pos):
        self.speed = -min(5, magnitude(sub(pos, self.pos)) / 10.0)
        self.laser = pos, 5

pygame.init()
quit = False
s = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
c = pygame.time.Clock()
ship = Ship()

FIRE = pygame.USEREVENT
pygame.time.set_timer(FIRE, 2000)

while not quit:
    quit = pygame.event.get(pygame.QUIT)
    if pygame.event.get(FIRE):
        ship.fire(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
    ship.set_target(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
    pygame.event.poll()
    ship.update()
    s.fill((0, 0, 0))
    ship.draw(s)
    pygame.display.flip()
    c.tick(60)
```

[image]