# Translate a vector along an axis so the vector length increases in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, vector, linear-algebra

I am facing a problem related to chemistry (Matter and modeling) but based on linear algebra and Python. Thus I am asking it here.

I have xyz coordinates of two molecules A and B (I removed the atom numbers for clarity).

```
A=[[-3.046233, -5.4e-05, 0.182027], [-2.084295, 5.1e-05, 0.033334], [-3.450141, 0.000367, -0.693385]]
B=[[2.911769, 4.4e-05, -0.165016], [3.305155, 0.771695, 0.262288], [3.305, -0.772028, 0.261672]]
```

I can calculate the distance between two points of A and B. The distance between A[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xjk0n.png) and B[0] is 4.99 unit. The problem is I need to fix the positions of A but move away B such the distance increases to 6,7,8 units and so on along the A[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xjk0n.png)-B[0] axis. I know this is translating a vector, but I do not know the translation vector.
Any help to tackle this?

Edit 1: (Following @Caridorc comment)
The problem is to drag atoms 4,5,6 along the 2-4 line, such that only the distance between 2 and 4 increases. But the 4-5 and 4-6 distances remain fixed.

[image: Problem image]

Comment: The first step is to [normalize the vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114921/vector-normalization). Now you have a unit vector (length 1). Multiply by the distance to get the vector of the proper magnitude along the original vector.

Comment: `move away B such the distance increases to 6,7,8` there are infinite ways to do this as you can move away up, down, left, right... there is more than one solution to your problem. Also please try to include an example drawing for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I am not sure how exactly you want the result to be, but here is how you might translate A away from B such that A1 and B0 are exactly 6 units, and their orientations are preserved.)

I like to use numpy for a lot of numerical linear algebra problems:

```
import numpy as np

# A and B have row vectors which are the positions of the points.
A=np.array([[-3.046233, -5.4e-05, 0.182027], [-2.084295, 5.1e-05, 0.033334], [-3.450141, 0.000367, -0.693385]])
B=np.array([[2.911769, 4.4e-05, -0.165016], [3.305155, 0.771695, 0.262288], [3.305, -0.772028, 0.261672]])

# The length of A1->B0 is 4.99 as you've mentioned:
A1B0_length = np.linalg.norm((A[1]-B[0]))

# Taking the unit direction vector B[0] -> A[1] by normalizing
drx_vec = A[1] - B[0]
drx_vec = drx_vec / np.linalg.norm(drx_vec)

# Choose the final length you want B[0]->A[1], then translate everything:
# Here I use 6 as an example,
translate_vec = drx_vec * 6
A_new = A + translate_vec
```

This moves all the points in A along the A[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#General_rotations)B[0] axis such that the distance between them are 6.
Should you wish to change the orientation,
you could translate A such that the pivot point is at origin, transpose A so that the positions are columns of A^T,
then multiply by a rotation matrix (see [Rotation Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#General_rotations)) on the left,  transpose it back, then translate it back to where it was.